# Dojo is submitting Extraneous Ajax Requests from disconnected/unrelated controls

Tags: ajax, checkbox, dojo, request, submit

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with checkboxes on a Dojo page. In the code below I have created a search form which makes an Ajax/xhrGet request when the search text is changed - this all works as expected.

However I also have a checkbox on the same page which, when clicked, is also submitting an Ajax request. Since I have not connected the checkbox to the search I have no idea why this is happening.

Is this a bug or is there something more subtle going on here?

Any ideas/suggestions?

TIA, 
BrendanC

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
        dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");
</script>

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="false" region="trailing" 
        style="width: 200px;">
            <script type="text/javascript"> var srch = dojo.byId ("djsearch"); dojo.connect(srch, "onchange", "getbyname"); </script>              
          Search              
          <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="dojosearch" value="Find" 
          trim="true" id="djsearch" propercase="true" style="width: 6em">

          <p></p>
          Tag Summary
          <div id='tagsummary'></div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of my problem. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Basically I did not issue the dojo.connect correctly - this needs to be done inside the 'addOnLoad' handler. In my initial code I was issuing the connect request on the page, but not in the required addOnLoad handler. The following code works correctly.

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

```
<script> 
  // Add the dojo.connect below     
  dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        // Connection s/b in 'addOnLoad' to work correctly
        var srch = dojo.byId ("djsearch");    
        dojo.connect(srch, "onchange", "getbyname");            
    });    
</script>
```